# Presenting a Custom UIViewcontroller when a local notification is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uilocalnotification

Im Creating a **Local notification** in **applicationDidEnterBackground** :

```
NSString *word;
word=[DictionaryHelper getWordOfTheDay];
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
localNotification.alertBody =("%@",word);
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]     applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Its displaying the local notification and its opening the **rootviewcontroller(initial)** of the app.

but i want to open a **specific UIViewController** when the local notification is clicked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your didReceiveLocalNotification:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Local notification received: %@", notification.alertBody);
    if ([notification.userInfo[@"notificationName"] isEqualToString:@"myLocalNotification"]) {
        [self.window.rootViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MainToNotification" sender:nil];
    }
}
```

My custom segue:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just check the dictionary userInfo in your `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. If it holds a key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey`, it means the app was launched through the tapping on the local notification and you can get a reference to the notification object in the userInfo dictionary.

More here: [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveLocalNotification:)

To present a different UIViewController, just init or instantiate your viewController for this case and set it to be your rootVC.

You can also use the method to respond to the notification:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Comment: in didReceiveLocalNotification, you can just instantiate your controller and do [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController: animated: completion:] instead of replacing your root controller. assuming this is a pop up message controller that you'd want to dismiss at some point.

Comment: Yes @mitrenegade , Iam going to present a UIViewcontroller, when the notification is clicked in the notification bar...